# jQuery: Update a html ordered list with each object from a JSON array each time I press a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-lists, submit-button

I am very new to jQuery, Javascript and DOM manipulation in general.
I am trying to build a simple interface to annotate a series of tweet pairs.
I have my tweet pairs stored as objects in a JSON array (the size is 4100 pairs).
I am trying to load in the list the first pair and then update the list with the next pair each time a "submit" type button is clicked.

The HTML code looks like:

```
<div class="inner cover">

  <ol type="A">
    <li><span id="full_tweet"></span></li><br>
    <li><span id="tweet_no_emoji"></span></li><br>
  </ol>  

  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="Class Tag" value="R">Redundant<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Class Tag" value="Non R">Non Redundant<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Class Tag" value="Non R + POS">Non Redundant + POS<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</div>
```

My JSON file looks like:

```
{ "Pairs": [
  {
     "full_tweet": "RT @USER: GRAYSON DOLAN is the one who is in awe with her as the best in home \ud83c\udfe1 she was meant to be a family but I love \u2764\ufe0f th\u2026 ", 
     "tweet_no_emoji": "RT @USER: GRAYSON DOLAN is the one who is in awe with her as the best in home  she was meant to be a family but I love \u2764\ufe0f th\u2026 "
   }, 
  {
     "full_tweet": "RT @USER: @USER Hey Stella, would you please SIGN AND RT this \ud83d\udc36", 
     "tweet_no_emoji": "RT @USER: @USER Hey Stella, would you please SIGN AND RT this "
    }, 
  {
     "full_tweet": "I don't care what you think as long as its about me \ud83c\udfb6", 
     "tweet_no_emoji": "I don't care what you think as long as its about me "
   }
  ]
}
```

My script:

```
$.getJSON('tweet_pairs3.json', function (data) {

  $.each(data.Pairs, function (i, Pairs) {
    var pair1 = ('<li><a href="#">' + Pairs.full_tweet + '</a></li>');
    $('#full_tweet').append(pair1);

    var pair2 = ('<li><a href="#">' + Pairs.tweet_no_emoji + '</a></li>');
    $('#tweet_no_emoji').append(pair2);
  }); //$.each(...)

}); //$.getJSON
```

This of course is appending all the items to the list, but what I'm looking   for is a way to append the first pair, then update the list with the next pair at each "submission".

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to get the desired output even though I am not sure this solution is optimal. 
With this code I am getting the first pair displayed in the list of my html page; then on each click over the "Submit" button the list is updated with the next element of my file. Once reached the last element by clicking on the Submit button I am redirected to another page.

```
$.getJSON('tweet_pairs3.json', function (data) {
  var pair1=[]; //I store the properties of the JSON in arrays so that I can get elements by indices
  var pair2=[];
      idx = 1;
  $.each(data.Pairs, function (i, Pairs) { //filling the empty arrays
    pair1.push(Pairs.full_tweet);
    pair2.push(Pairs.tweet_no_emoji);   
  }); //$.each(...)
  $('#full_tweet').html(pair1[0]); //appending only the first pair to the list
  $('#tweet_no_emoji').html(pair2[0]);

  $('#sub').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    $('#full_tweet').html(pair1[idx]); //changing list content starting from elements at index 1 in my arrays
    $('#tweet_no_emoji').html(pair2[idx]);

    idx += 1
    if (idx >= pair1.length) {
      window.location.href = "Zlast_page.html"; //once the index is equal to the array length if I click on the button I am redirected to a page stating that the task is complete
    } //if()

  }); //$('#sub').on

}); //$.getJSON*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <div class="inner cover">
  <ol type="A" id="full_tweet">

  </ol>  
  <ol type="A" id="tweet_no_emoji">

  </ol>  

  <form>
  <input type="radio" name="Class Tag" value="R">Redundant<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Class Tag" value="Non R">Non Redundant<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Class Tag" value="Non R + POS">Non Redundant + POS<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</div>


$.getJSON('tweet_pairs3.json', function (data) {
var pair1='';
var pair2='';
$.each(data.Pairs, function (i, Pairs) {
  pair1 += '<li><a href="#">' + Pairs.full_tweet + '</a></li>';
  pair2 += '<li><a href="#">' + Pairs.tweet_no_emoji + '</a></li>';   
});
$('#full_tweet').html(pair1);
$('#tweet_no_emoji').html(pair2);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but with your solution I still get all the pairs in the same page (which is the same output that I am already getting with my code). I want only the first pair and then update the list with the next pair after each click on the Submit button.